# custom date formatting C#

Tags: c#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
     dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy";
}
```

Result: `25-08-2016`

This is working. However, the second time I run it, the `mm` value gets increased by `1`

So the Result becomes: `25-09-2016`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try MM instead of mm. If I remember correctly, mm is "minutes" ;)

Comment: Lower case "mm" is in fact minutes, "MM" will give 2 digit month. Full Spec can be found on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

- `mm` is **minutes**.
- `MM` is months

This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Use `dd-MM-yyyy` instead.

(That said, why not adopt the unambiguous ISO 8601 format, or respect the user's regional settings by using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?)

Comment: I just realised this question was posted back in 2016 but ended up on the frontpage due to a post-edit. Welp, now this will never get marked as the accepted answer :)

Comment: sending Kudos to you